# Pseudocode for adding 2 until number is 100

Tags: pseudocode

I have a pseudocode assignment for a class. I have to design a program to output every even number starting with 2 and going to 100. I need someone to tell me if this is correct. If it isn't could someone point me in the right direction?

```
start
    Declarations
      num A = 0
      num B = 100
      num C
    while A < B
      C = A + 2
      Output C
   Endwhile
stop
```

Comment: No, it's not. StackOverflow should probably be renamed to ClassWorkflow.

Comment: That will print `2,2,2,2,2,2,2,` etc...

Comment: So do I need to get rid of the num A and the others, and just use numbers? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start
    Declarations
      num A = 0
      num B = 100
    while A < B
      A = A + 2
      Output A
   Endwhile
stop